# Error Checkbox parseRequest

Tags: java, checkbox, requests

Tengo un problema con esta parte de codigo, si no selecciono el checkbox me falla el programa.

**Servlet.java**

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

String image=items.get(0).getName();
String name=items.get(1).getString();
String checkbox1=items.get(2).getString();
```

**Index.jsp**

```
<form action="Register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><input type="file" name="image">
<p><input type="text" name="name">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="yes">
<p><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```